# Who's on the milk carton in Spider-Man: No Way Home?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

In *Spider-Man: No Way Home*, MJ takes a carton of milk from the fridge in

> the glamorous and mystical undercroft of the Sanctum Santorum.

I thought I saw a missing person picture on it, but I couldn't make out who was meant to be in the picture. Who was it?

Comment: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/7E2VsxoLXNA/maxresdefault.jpg

Comment: @Clockwork: canon!

Comment: Can you please post a picture of the carton of milk?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica: I mean, not without risking Covid infection by going to see the movie again, and risking getting thrown out for taking a picture.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is the box MJ is shown holding in the image below (taken from [a Twitter feed](https://twitter.com/spiderman3news/status/1470512212586512397)) the one you had in mind?

[image]

If so, the box was actually packaging for a goatee shaving template, and the face pictured on the front was presumably that of a random model, rather than anyone we might realistically be expected to recognise.

Comment: Ooh yeah that looks like it. Nice! 

Comment: Also looks a little like John Cusack, although I don’t think it’s him.

Comment: I don't know, it _somewhat_ looks like Robert Downey Jr.

Comment: TIL there's such a thing as a commercially-sold "goatee shaving template".  Who knew?

Comment: @davidbak In an infinite multiverse, there are infinite assistive devices for male grooming.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - oh sure, many-worlds quantum interpretation and all that - but I'm talking about a Google search in _this_ universe _I'm living in!_

Answer (score -4):

I think it was a photo of Dr Strange as missing.

Comment: Ok, what do you base this on?

Comment: Oh yeah probably a good shout — I think I remember it looking like the guy had a goatee, and Strange did basically disappear when he went to Kamar-Taj eh.